# Why am i getting a stackoverflow error in my recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

This is the recursive method I am trying to use but i keep getting a stack overflow method... I cant tell what is wrong with it?

```
public class NUMWAYS_JENRODRIGUEZ {         
    public static long numWays (int n, int k, int [] D) {          
        if (n == 0)
            return 1; 

        if (n < 0) 
            return 0; 

        if (k <=0 && n >= 1) 
            return 0;

        return numWays( n, k - 1, D ) + 
               numWays( n-D[k-1], k, D );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you call `numWays( n, k - 1, D )` with `n < 1`, the recursions will never end.  You need to check your recusion logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the recursion does stop in that case, thats when `k <=0 && n >= 1`

Comment: @Jennifer with what input are you obtaining stack overlfow??

Comment: `int [] D1 = {0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 35};
          int k1 = D1.length - 1;
          int n1 = 150;
      
          int [] D2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
          int k2 = D2.length - 1;
     
 
            
          System.out.println("Recursive, numWays(" + n1 + 
          ", " + k1 + ", D1)  =  " + numWays(n1, k1, D1));`

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the complete example, rather than using comments. Additionally, it would help if you could show what diagnostic steps you've taken to understand the problem. (For example, which of those samples is causing the problem?)